# Working with attribute routing in mvc

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0

On my login page I have a dropdownlist to change the culture of the application for which I am doing a Ajax call to set the culture. By default I have set to 'en_US'.

My issue is when I am login directly without changing the culture I am able to login successfully, but when I change the culture and tries to login, I am not able to do that. Is this happening because of AJAX call made, which makes custom attribute not registered ?

Also, my login method has a custom attribute defined. Below is the code.

**AJAX Call**

```
 $('#ddlLanguages').change(function () {
        var val = $('#ddlLanguages').val()
        createCookie('culturecookie', val, 7);


        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '/Account/GetCultureNew',
            data: { culturename: val },
            success: function (result) {

                $("#logo-group").html('');
                $(document.body).html('');
                $(document.body).html(result);

            },
            error: function (data) {
                //alert('Error');
            }
        });

    });
```

**Ajax Method in controller**

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult GetCultureNew(string culturename)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(culturename) & culturename.Contains("#"))
        {
            string[] strdata = culturename.Split('#');

            if (strdata.Length > 0)
            {
                AppTenant tenant = HttpContext.Session.GetObjectFromJson<AppTenant>("TenantInfo");

                if (tenant != null)
                {
                    tenant.LoggedInCulture = strdata[0];
                    tenant.LanguageID = Convert.ToInt32(strdata[1]);

                    HttpContext.Session.SetObjectAsJson("TenantInfo", tenant);
                }
            }
        }
        List<SelectListItem> items = new List<SelectListItem>();
        items = HttpContext.Session.GetObjectFromJson<List<SelectListItem>>("LanguageData");

        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            if (item.Value == culturename)
            {
                item.Selected = true;
            }
            else
            {
                item.Selected = false;
            }
        }

        var itemsString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(items);

        CookieOptions obj = new CookieOptions();
        obj.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(3);
        Response.Cookies.Append("Languagelist", itemsString, obj);

        var viewModel = new LMS_User { ReturnUrl = string.Empty, LanguageList = items };

        return View("Login", viewModel);
    }
```

**Login Method**

```
[HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ResponseCache(NoStore = true, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None)]
    [Route("Admin/Login/{clietname}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login([Bind(include: "Email,Password,RememberMe")] LMS_User model, string returnUrl)
    {
          // my login logic
    }
```

**EDIT :- 1**
**Login partial View**

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-5 col-lg-4">
<div class="well no-padding">
    <form action="@Url.Action("login", "account")" method="POST" id="login-form" class="smart-form client-form">
        <header>
            @obj["SingnIn"]
        </header>
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

        <fieldset>
            <section>
                <label asp-for="LanguageList">@obj["LanguageList"] </label>
                @Html.DropDownList("Languages", Model.LanguageList, null, new { id = "ddlLanguages", @class = "form-control" })
            </section>
            <section>
                <label asp-for="Email">@obj["Email"]</label>
                <label class="input">
                    <i class="icon-append fa fa-user"></i>

                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "form-control" }) 
                    <b class="tooltip tooltip-top-right"><i class="fa fa-user txt-color-teal"></i>>@obj["tooltipEmail"]</b>
                    <span asp-validation-for="Email" class="text-danger"></span>
                </label>
            </section>

            <section>
                <label asp-for="Password">@obj["Password"]</label>
                <label class="input">
                    <i class="icon-append fa fa-lock"></i>
                    @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "form-control" })
                    <b class="tooltip tooltip-top-right"><i class="fa fa-lock txt-color-teal"></i>@obj["tooltippassword"] </b>
                    <span asp-validation-for="Password" class="text-danger"></span>
                </label>
                <div class="note">
                    <a href="@Url.Action("forgotpassword", "account")"><i class="fa fa-frown-o"></i> @obj["Forgot_password?"]</a>
                </div>
            </section>

            <section>
                <label class="checkbox">
                    <input asp-for="RememberMe" />

                    <i></i>@obj["Remember_Me"]
                </label>
            </section>

            <footer>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                    @obj["SingnIn"]
                </button>
            </footer>


        </fieldset>
    </form>


</div>
@{ await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_SocialMedia"); }
```

Edit 2:-Entire login view

```
<div id="content" class="container">
    <div class="row">

        @{ await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_LoginText"); }
        @{ await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_LoginPartial"); }

    </div>
</div>
```

However if I add  `location.reload()` in AJAX success function, then by changing the culture I can login successfully.

Any help on this appreciated !

Comment: Hi, are you accidentally changing the anti-forgery key? If you do so the post wont be successful ... can you provide the cshtml ?

Comment: @WickStargazer I have updated question with login view code, in view I have added `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()`, but I am not using/changing it in action method.

Comment: This code $(document.body).html(result); is resetting the anti-forgery key. I am not sure if it affects the post or not if the page is not refreshed. 
Try  [ValidateInput(false)] on the login attribute and see if it fires.

Also try to see the network request params after changing the culture to see what is sent to the server.

Comment: @Rohit What do you mean by "I am not able to do that"? What are the symptoms?

Comment: @Kamo if I change the culture and tries to login, I am not getting logged into the application. It says Network not found https:// localhost:50874, however the url should be https:// localhost:50874/account/login/myclientname

Comment: @Rohit Did you check the form action after the language is changed?

Comment: @WickStargazer in browser you are saying? When I do View Source on browser it displays the previous form values with action, but at the same time if I inspect the element the form action is NOT available. Am i missing something ?

Comment: @Rohit Yes that is the issue. the view source is not updated. When you do the $(document.body).html(result); the action goes missing. That is your bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do the `$(document.body).html(result);`

**The action part of the form goes missing**. Hence it does not know where to post to.

Hope i have been of some help :)

Comment: So, how can I update the text of the form controls with the selected language ?

Comment: Try to debug why the view is not rendering action. Check the network request what is returned.
For a quick fix i suggest you use a partial view within the form with a container div.

Comment: My login view already has 2 partials, please see my Edit 2, of which `_LoginPartial` requires a model

Comment: Suggest that you dont re-render the Form element and send back. However i never had any issue. Can you please dump your ajax response after changing language?

Comment: I am sharing the link where I have dumped ajax response as its bit lengthy, https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3r_zMG9Y-HJSV9vbjVIb2xlaG8/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Hi as i stated the return form has <form action="/" which is the culprit.

Do not know why, but you should be only rendering the <div> sections of the form or just reload the page.

The architecture you are looking for is to load the languages into JSON and bind them using something like angular or reactjs